Configure AutoClusterFailover for Pulsar Client
I'm following the documentation of Spring for Apache Pulsar https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/0.1.0-M1/reference/html/#pulsar-client, but I can't find the configuration options for failover configuration. Is cluster failover configuration supported on this library? How can I add it?

This feature was added in Spring Boot 3.3.0-RC1
which uses Spring Pulsar 1.1.0-RC1. It looks like we did not update the docs with this info yet - but we will do that before the GA release.
In the meantime you can get an idea how to configure this via the tests.

The docs have been updated to include a section for this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/reference/reference/pulsar/pulsar-client.html#auto-cluster-failover
